# reduce method inside a for loop - JS

Tags: javascript, reduce

I am trying to loop through array of entries using a for loop and use the reduce method, but the reduce returns after the first entry, never getting to the second, third, etc entries to push the result to an array v.

Any thoughts?

```
export const groupEventData = eventData => {
    console.log(eventData)
    // returns[{
    //     "id": "141",
    //     "name": "00333",
    //     "no_transmission": true,
    //     "low_battery" :true,
    // },
    // {
    //     "id": "307",
    //     "name": "01163",
    //     "no_transmission": true,
    //     "low_data_rate": true,
    // }
    // ]

    // now let's group similar event types
    let v = [];
    let types = ["no_transmission", "low_data_rate", "low_battery"]; 
    for (let x = 0; x <= types.length; x++) {
        let data = eventData.reduce((acc, i) => {
            if (!acc[i[types[x]]] && typeof i[types[x]] !== 'undefined') {
                acc[i[types[x]]] = [i]
            }
            else if (Array.isArray(acc[i[types[x]]])) {
                acc[i[types[x]]].push(i);
            }
            else if (typeof acc[i[types[x]]] === 'object') {
                acc[i[types[x]]] = [acc[i[types[x]]]]
                acc[i[types[x]]].push(i)
            }
            return acc;
        }, {});
        // Doesn't add a property for the type if there are no data
        Object.keys(data).length && v.push({ [types[x]: data });
        return v;
    };

}
```

Comment: Can you show your input as a [mcve]? This leaves a bit too much to the imagination (`type`, `types`, `eventData`, actual/expected output). Thanks.

Comment: More importantly, `getEventTypes()` - is this possible a sync?

Comment: thank you, clarified

Comment: Thanks but it's still needlessly abstract. It should be easy to put this into a form with clearly hardcoded input/output data structures that can be executed as a [runnable snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do). What output are you trying to achieve here (show it explicitly/literally)? Also, this seems agnostic of React, so I'd encourage removing the tag if it doesn't matter. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think so, all I want to do is to be able to loop the reduce function the number of times as the length of the types array (in the case above, it's 3 times) but it returns after done the first entry.. makes sense because there is return acc. What I am asking how to loop the reduce function n number of times and store in v array

Comment: What is the value of `type` in your function? bc?

Comment: yes, a string 'bc'

Comment: i only use it to get the correct types array, it could be different for different cases, but honestly for this example it doesn't matter - updated the question to exclude this

Comment: okay and what are you trying to achieve with the reduce function?

Comment: pretty much group by repeating value, for example no_transmission: true repeats twice -> groups them by true: Array(2)

Comment: @John see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63958748/aggregate-same-key-values-into-an-array-and-avoid-undefined/63962887?noredirect=1#comment113107515_63962887

Comment: I thought that code looked familiar :). See how I created that Stack Snippet, provided the code and data so that it could be run easily to see the output? You can do that in the question too, to help people answer. Also see how we went back and forth about how you wanted the output? That could be prevented if you could just show an example of how you want the output displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `return v` inside your for loop. Try bumping it below the curly brace immediately beneath it. Right now the for loop is iterating only once and then returning a value.

Worked for me below:

```
const eventData = [
  {"id": "141","name": "00333","no_transmission": true,"low_battery": true},
  {"id": "307","name": "01163","no_transmission": true,"low_data_rate": true}
]

const type = 'bc'

const types = ["no_transmission", "low_data_rate", "low_battery"]

const groupEventData = (eventData, type) => {
  let v = [];
  for (let x = 0; x <= types.length; x++) {
    let data = eventData.reduce((acc, i) => {
      if (!acc[i[types[x]]] && typeof i[types[x]] !== 'undefined') {
        acc[i[types[x]]] = [i]
      }
      else if (Array.isArray(acc[i[types[x]]])) {
        acc[i[types[x]]].push(i);
      }
      else if (typeof acc[i[types[x]]] === 'object') {
        acc[i[types[x]]] = [acc[i[types[x]]]]
        acc[i[types[x]]].push(i)
      }
      return acc;
    }, {});
    Object.keys(data).length && v.push({ [`${types[x]}_${type}`]: data });
  };
  return v;
}

console.log('groupEventData', groupEventData(eventData, type))
```